# how can I fix a wsgi error on beanstlak app using Python and fastapi

Tags: python, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, fastapi

I am using Python and fasatpi (web framework).
My application.py file is:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn

application = FastAPI()


@application.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}



if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("application:application", host="127.0.0.1", port=5000, log_level="info")
```

This runs fine on local machine by running python application.py

However when I deploy to an elastic beanstalk on AWS, after multiple failed attempts and also experimenting with a Procfile, as follows:

```
web: uvicorn application:app --host=0.0.0.0 --port=${PORT:-5000}
```

And repeated error is:

[

```
Tue Jun 16 08:58:16.659854 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 8242] AH00163: Apache/2.4.43 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.6.10 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jun 16 08:58:16.659870 2020] [core:notice] [pid 8242] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Tue Jun 16 08:58:19.704522 2020] [:error] [pid 8247] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] mod_wsgi (pid=8247): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py'.
[Tue Jun 16 08:58:19.704608 2020] [:error] [pid 8247] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'send'
```

How can I fix this? Many thanks.

Comment: Why you are using uvicorn.run in your code? It's unnecesarry if you are running with Procfile.

Comment: thank you, so what should the Procfile say? If using a Procfile is the right approach ...

Comment: Your Procfile seems ok to me. try to run it again after deleting if name main in your code